# Qt Maps (QML) application window is blank

Tags: c++, qt, qml

This is my code for a Qt Maps application I'm trying to make.
http://pastebin.com/PNcYivM9    - main.qml

I'm using Qt Creator on Ubuntu 14.04. 
When I do compile and run the code the application window is blank.

I haven't edited the main.ui.qml apart from adding the Qt Location import.

I've also added the location keyword in the .pro file
Any help would be appreciated since I can't really find any tutorials on maps.

EDIT:
Here's the code

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtLocation 5.4

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true


    Plugin{
        id: osmplugin
        name:"osm"
    }

    Map {
        plugin: osmplugin

        id: map
        zoomLevel: (maximumZoomLevel - minimumZoomLevel)/2


//        center {
//            latitude: -27.5796
//            longitude: 153.1003
//        }

        // Enable pinch gestures to zoom in and out
        gesture.flickDeceleration: 3000
        gesture.enabled: true

//    center {
//        latitude: -27.5796
//        longitude: 153.1003
//    }
    }




}
```

Comment: In my code, I've left the centre property in comments since it shows an error
"Invalid grouped property access"

Comment: Most of us will never see your code because it's on an external site instead of included in your post.

Comment: I'll include it then. I thought it would be easier this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Map` has no dimensions set, so it's going to default to a width and height of zero.  To see that this is the case, add the following to your Map component:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log("Dimensions: ", width, height)
}
```

This will print out:

> Dimensions:  0 0

So you either need to set the dimensions to a value other than zero, or use the `anchor` property to attach the dimensions to the parent's anchors.

Comment: Is the plugin being used the right way? I didn't install anything for the plugin I just wrote the code.
I'll try and add the anchors now.

Comment: @user3927312 I believe so.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I have another problem now though. Like I mentioned above if I remove the comments on the "center" property it says invalid grouped property access. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Sounds like a separate question.

Comment: I'll post it as one then?